# Flask app returning 404 in Xampp

Tags: python, apache, flask, http-status-code-404

I currently have my files structured as:

```
/xampp/code/menumaster_project    
menumaster
    __init__.py
    menumaster_app.py
    sqltables.py
```

In my `Apache` `httpd.conf` file I have:

```
<IfModule wsgi_module>
  <VirtualHost *:8081>
    WSGIScriptAlias /myapp C:/xampp/htdocs/flaskapp/flask.wsgi    
    <Directory C:/xampp/htdocs/flaskapp>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

`flask.wsgi`

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, 'C:/xampp/code/menumaster_project')

from menumaster import app as application
```

The file that contains all my routes is `menumaster_app.py`:

```
@app.route('/restaurants', methods = ['GET'])
```

I am trying to access my app on `localhost` through `http://localhost:8081/myapp/restaurants` however I am receiving a `404` error.

I'm also not sure how my app is supposed to know that `menumaster_app.py` is the main file that needs to be called initially.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import menumaster_app after defining your Flask app, so that the code is loaded and the routes are registered.

`__init__.py`

```
# ...
app = Flask(__name__)
# ...
from menumaster import menumaster_app
```

Be sure to import `menumaster_app` *after* any objects that *it* will import from `__init__.py`, to avoid circular imports.

---

<sub>As a side note, it is pretty confusing to name your views "menumaster_app", when that module neither defines the package menumaster nor the Flask app.  Typically the file with views in it is called `views.py`.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

This article was very helpful: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/packages/

I ended up following what was stated there and ended up with:

```
menumaster
    runserver.py
    menumaster
        views.py
        sqltables.py
```

**runserver.py**

```
from menumaster import app
app.run(debug=True)
```

**views.py**

```
@app.route('/restaurants', methods = ['GET'])
```

**__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
import menumaster.views
```

**.wsgi**

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'C:/xampp/code/menumaster')
from menumaster import app as application
```

Hope this helps someone.